# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
            <script type="text/babel">
                class Frame extends React.Component{
                    render(){
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <h2 className="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
                                    <span className="os-animation" data-os-animation="lightSpeedOut" data-os-animation-delay="5s">
                                            {this.props.message}
                                    </span>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
                class DrawAnimation extends React.Component{
                    constructor(props){
                        super(props)
                        this.state = {
                            animationArr:["Web developer", "University Student", "New generation's genius"],
                            active:0,
                            timer: setInterval(this.changeActive, 5000)
                        }
                        this.changeActive = this.changeActive.bind(this)
                    }
                    changeActive(){
                        this.setState({active: this.state.active + 1})
                    }
                    render(){
                        return (
                            <Frame message={this.state.animationArr[this.state.active]}/>
                        )
                    }
                }

                ReactDOM.render(
                    <DrawAnimation/>,
                    document.getElementById('animation-container')
                );
            </script>
```

This is my inline block React code and I got the error of undefined property active when calling changeActive from setInterval. I have done binding it, but still get this. 
Can anybody know what to do with this?

Comment: Hello, move `this.changeActive = this.changeActive.bind(this)` before the state init (before setInterval).

Comment: You can use an arrow function so no need to bind anything. Just an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#animation-container');
```

**Use this instead of **
                    document.getElementById('animation-container')